# How can I fix broken image links in my pug included markdown files?

Tags: pug, markdown-it

i just need to rebase the incoming links in the markdown, so that they're relative to the pug document

**structure**

```
index.pug
articles/
  my-article.md
  my-image.jpg
```

**pug**

```
.article-body
  include:markdown-it articles/my-article.md
```

**markdown**

```
# my cool article

![my cool image](my-image.jpg)
```

i'd really rather not change my markdown link to `articles/my-image.jpg`, because that would break the markdown preview for editing, which would be an awful developer experience

Comment: the package markdown-it-replace-link doesn't look like a viable solution -- it is not compatible with the pug-cli, only the pug node api -- and the node api does *not* include watch mode functionality -- and i can't abandon watch mode just to fix the links..

Comment: You could use gulp and gulp-replace to regex the markdown paths

Comment: Or change your structure so that the path can stay consistent